# How to make a python program as a daemon service in raspberry pi 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi3

i am setting up a code to become a daemon service but everytime i am trying to start it says there is no module named cv2  and therefore service doesnt starts  but when  i am running my code through terminal as python3 path to my code it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

That's because cv2 is not installed on your raspberry pi. You can install cv2 by running the following command:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

To make pip work on the pi, here's some documentation: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/software/python.md

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It is installed every dependency was also there, its because pyzbar cv2 directory location was different,just had to move them to current working directory.